# Reenable Popup Hint

Tags: crusader-kings-2

For one of the circular popup hints at the top middle of the screen, the Create/Usurp Title one, I accidentally right-clicked and hid it permanently. How do I reenable it? I can't find it in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

This was previously a bug and has been fixed in the Monks and Mystics release (At least I thought it was a bug as I never saw that option in the the side panel).

Quoting from [the wiki](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Notifications):

> In order to restore disabled or dismissed alerts:
>
> 1. Open the outliner category configuration Outliner config.png
> 2. Check the box Disabled alerts
> 3. In the outliner, click on the alerts that need to be restored

Graphical representation can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but at the right of the screen there is a panel with a summary of your army, provinces etc. If I'm not wrong, you can reactivate those messages from there.